Adding Spring JMS listeners dynamically
I've a Java Spring boot application, in which I need to dynamically create multiple Spring JMS listeners at runtime, depending on the configuration in a table in Sql server database.
This configuration includes name of the various listeners and their corresponding properties(for e.g. hostname, channel name, queue manager, queue name, port number, etc). The listeners can receive multiple messages concurrently from different sources.
So far, I've thought of two different approaches for this requirement, as shown below.
Wondering which of these approaches is better with respect concurrency, performance and scaalability? or is there any other better approach?
Approach #1
@Override
public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    List<ListenerConfig> listenerList = fetchListenerConfigsFromDatabase();
    listenerList.forEach(listener -> {
        SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
        endpoint.setId(listener);
        endpoint.setDestination(listener);
        try {
            endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> executorService.submit(() -> processMessage(message)));
            registrar.setContainerFactory(mqJmsListenerContainerFactory());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.info("Exception - " + e);
        }
        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
    });
}

private void processMessage(Message message){
        try {
          logger.info("ID: {} Destination {}", message.getJMSMessageID(), message.getJMSDestination());
        }
        catch (JMSException e) {
          logger.info("Exception occurred while reading message - " + e);
        }
      }
}
-

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Approach #2
@Override
public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
List<ListenerConfig> listenerList = fetchListenerConfigsFromDatabase();
int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
  listenerList.forEach(listener -> {
  executorService.execute(new Runnable() {     
  SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setId(listener);
    endpoint.setDestination(listener);
    try {
      endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> processMessage());
      registrar.setContainerFactory(mqJmsListenerContainerFactory());
    }
    catch (JMSException e) {
      logger.info("Exception - " + e);
    }
    registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
   } 
});

}

@Async
private void processMessage(Message message){
        try {
          logger.info("ID: {} Destination {}", message.getJMSMessageID(), message.getJMSDestination());
        }
        catch (JMSException e) {
          logger.info("Exception occurred while reading message - " + e);
        }
      }
}

I've tried approach #2 so far in which I configured two listeners in the db. It seems to be working good for about 2000 concurrent messages for each of the two configured listeners.
I need to make sure the approach is able to :

Gracefully scale up to 5000-7000 concurrent messages
Avoid a state in which a listener has become unresponsive and hence not able to read/process the message, although the application is up and running.
Avoid a situation in which I need to restart the application on the server, because of point #2 above.

Thank you for ur help!
